# matlab plot jump discontinuity

Tags: matlab, plot

Is it possible to plot a sequence of data without interpolating them?
I would like to keep the value of one data point until the value of the next one.

So for example:

I have my time vector

```
time = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

and `datapoints =[3 0 1 4 5 6]`

I would like that the line of my plot is 3 from time(1) till time(2) and then it should change in time(2) to take the value 0.
Basically in correspondence of the time 2 my plot should assume both the value 3 and 0 (jump discontinuity)...

I hope I was clear.

Comment: why not using a `bar` diagram?

Comment: because I have multiple lines on the same plot... I would like to use the plot function..

Comment: yes thanks! I didn't know the stairs plot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A short answer: yes you can.

Use the [stairs()](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function.

```
time=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
datapoints = [3 0 1 4 5 6];

stairs(time,datapoints)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

you have to duplicate the times as well the datapoints and plot them shifted in order to get the staircase-style:

```
time = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
datapoints =[3 0 1 4 5 6];  
datapoints = [datapoints, datapoints];
[time, idx] = sort([time, time]);   
time(1) = [];   
datapoints = datapoints(idx);
datapoints(end) = [];
plot(time,datapoints)
```